# How to order by date string using Pipes in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, pipe

I need a sorting method for my posts, I get all the posts but starting with the oldest, i want something to bring me first my new posts based on the property [formattedDate: string] or at least based on the [datePost: Date].
I have a problem with ordering my posts , i tried a lot of options but i always get the same error:

```
ERROR TypeError: item.sort is not a function
```

I don't know what to do next.. please help me :<

**This is my sorting pipe:**

```
 transform(array: PostG[], args: string): PostG[] {

    if(!array || array === undefined || array.length === 0) return null;
  
    array.forEach((item: any) => {
      item.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.formattedDate < b.formattedDate) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a.formattedDate > b.formattedDate) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      }); 
      console.log(item.formattedDate);
      return item.formattedDate;
    })
    }
```

**This is the interface for the post:**

```
export interface PostG {
    getTime();
    author:  { [key: string]: Author};
    datePost: Date;
    description: string
    dislike: number[];
    formattedDate: string;
    images: string[];
    like: number[];
    linkEdit: string;
    link:string;
    slug: string;
    title: string
    uniqueID: string;
}
```

**And here I subscribe for posts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.http.get(this.apiKey).subscribe((data: any) =>{   
        this.allPosts = data.data.post;
        console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Aqua, you shoul use `array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {..}` NOT `array.forEach(item=>item.sort(...)`

Comment: I tried this too , but I get all my arrays without any change. I used the pipe on the ngFor and doesnt sort my posts because i think it can't access the property formattedDate.

Comment: formattedDate is in the way yyyy-MM-dd?, if has values should work.NOTE in the own function sort you can add a `console.log(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

Hi I asked a friend that did a sorting method for nodeJs and he said he used reverse();
So then I realised i just have to change signs the other way and use the 'Date' property for sorting to get the new posts first.

This is the final code:

```
 transform(array: PostG[], args: string): PostG[] {

    if(!array || array === undefined || array.length === 0) return null;
  
      array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
        if (a.datePost > b.datePost) {
          return -1;
        } else if (a.datePost < b.datePost) {
          return 1;
        } else {
          return 0;
        }
      });
      console.log(array);
      return array;
    }
```

Thanks!